# Ubuntu works in try out but not when installed, how to fix?

Tags: system-installation

I've got quite a problem with it, perhaps the problem lies with me but I thought I fixed it, I believe the opposite now... Anyhow, I started off with a 64-Bit Windows 7 platform and I wanted something new then the same boring windows, I heard about Ubuntu before but I didn't see a reason to change it. Now I had found my reason, so what did I do was do the installation via an USB, I went "try out before installation" first and it worked perfectly, however... When I installed it, deleted my Window 7 and tried to reboot with my fresh oh-so-clean new OS, it didn't want to load. At a certain point it said to boot up from a bootable option or something like that. Where it came to was that I couldn't load it up. Now, I wanted to switch back to Windows 7 because it didn't work and now I can't switch back because my harddrive switched modus because of Linux files (From NTFS to 4ex or something, I forgot). I'm currently typing this in the try out version of Ubuntu since I can't switch back to either Windows 7 or to the installed version of Ubuntu. So, my question follows: Can I fix it by keeping Ubuntu? Because I like Ubuntu.

Also a side note: I'm a total noob when it comes down to this sort of things.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please register one account. Use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a few youtube videos should help :

We all have been there at the newb stage, 
just watch guides and stuff lots of resources, i think you are screwing up at the installation of ubuntu from the USB drive, but that would be much clear after watching

[Watch Videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIF8e_5F9B4)

Comment: I'm not, I've done it according via a youtube video but I'll try again. If it doesn't work, I'll come back to the subject :l

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back to Windows 7, you deleted it!  You'd have to reinstall it, which you can do.  Your harddrive switching "modes" is just a different file system.  You are running EXT4.  If you boot off a CD and install Windows it will format it back to NTFS which Windows uses.  You can also set your harddrive to two separate modes (which I will call file systems for now on) by partitioning it into two logical drives.

So, now we need more information to figure out why the install did not work.  If you have a USB key which is formatted to boot off of, I recommend running through the install again.  Boot off of the USB, choose to install instead of try, select the first option to Install Ubuntu on its own (since Windows is already deleted you said), and let it work its magic.  When you reboot, make sure the USB key is out and the only operating system your computer should be able to detect is Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem is, if I do what you say it answers at me: "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected."